# How do I run a loop within a Metal fragment shader?

Tags: swift, macos, metal

Is it possible to do this?  I don't want a a loop that can possibly go on for infinity, and I have experience using for loops in GLSL.  However, in Metal, I can't find a way to loop inside the fragment shader.  I tried `for` and `while`, but they both did not work.  Then, I implemented a recursive function

```
rayHit ray(vector_float3 origin, vector_float3 direction, int steps, int maxSteps, float depth)
{
    vector_float3 dir = vector_normalized(direction);
    vector_float3 p = origin; //point or direction vector times depth

    rayHit hitData;
    if (steps < maxSteps)
    {
        hitData = ray(origin, direction, steps+1, maxSteps, depth);
    }
    else
    {
        hitData.pos = origin;
        hitData.normal = -direction;
        hitData.depth = vector_length(direction);
        hitData.steps = 100;
    }
    
    
    
    return hitData;
}
```

but I got the error "Fragment function calls recursive code".  From all this, it appears that loops are intended to be impossible in Metal.  Is there any sort of workaround for this?  I'm trying to build some raymarching code, but I don't know how to do it without loops.

EDIT: Syntax was wrong, things seem to be working now.

Comment: `for` and `while` do work in Metal. What do you mean to say by "both did not work"?

Comment: What I mean is that any way that I try to call a for loop via the fragment shader, it doesn’t work.  Can’t use recursion called from the fragment shader, and both loops cause compile errors.  If you can provide a bit of code for me to test, i can try it out and show you the result.

Comment: It's the same `for` and `while` as they are in C++. What compile errors do you see? Recursive function calls are indeed unavailable, because the shaders don't really have a stack.

Comment: Erm, it appears I got the syntax wrong and it didn't recognize 'for' as a function or something like that. Sorry for the false alarm, and thanks for the help!